# Group datatable entries by row value after having separated

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview, datatable

***Whats happening:***  I have a table consisting of Name, ID, Comments.  Each ID is unique unless the user submits more than 1 entry.  At that point that user may then have 3 rows where the ID is the same to show these entries were all entered by 1 user and they belong together.

Below I'll post what I had done originally to separate these into separate datagridview's with buttons below each one that will eventually be used to work with the datagrid entries above it.

So this leads into 2 things I've trying to figure out and haven't had much luck through trial and error and Google researching.

1.)  How can I make this put any entries in the datatable that have the same ID into the same datagridview rather than creating a separate datagrid for each one.

2.)  Assuming the above can be done how would I, if possible, go about making the button generating below each one only correspond to the datagrid above it?  Can each datagrid and button although created programatically be assigned a unique ID that allows each one to correspond to the other?

```
    Dim dst As New DataSet
    For i As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim intLastRow As Integer = i
        If intLastRow > DT.Rows.Count - 1 Then intLastRow = DT.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim dtbNew As DataTable = DT.Clone
        dtbNew.TableName = DT.TableName
        For j As Integer = i To intLastRow
            dtbNew.ImportRow(DT.Rows(j))
        Next j
        dst.Tables.Add(dtbNew)
    Next i

    For Each table As DataTable In dst.Tables
        Dim DGV As New DataGridView
        Dim BTN As New Button
        BTN.Text = "Show Details"
        BTN.Width = 120
        DGV.DataSource = table
        DGV.Width = 800
        DGV.Height = 80
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(DGV)
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(BTN)
    Next
    FlowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(FlowLayoutPanel1.Top)
```

**Errors**

```
Dim DT As New DataTable
    DT.Load(SQLMP)

    Dim groups As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, DataRow)) = DT.Select.GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("ORDER_ID"))
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid

Comment: Try replacing
`Dim groups As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, DataRow)) = DT.Select.GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("ORDER_ID"))` by `Dim groups = DT.Select.GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("ORDER_ID"))`. What type is inferred to `groups` then?

Comment: Wait a minute :-) what type is the field **"ORDER_ID"**? If it is not an Integer but a String or whatever else, it is there Cast is failing...

Comment: No its an integer.

Comment: Just one more question before it beats me (doesn't mean it's impossible, but we'll have to drop Linq and rely on good old "For Each...Next" loop)... May the field "ORDER_ID" in some occasion be empty, there is, have DBNull as its value? If so, instead of `row.Field(Of Integer)("ORDER_ID")`, we'll have to use a nullable type: `row.Field(Of Integer?)("ORDER_ID").GetValueOrDefault`

Comment: I finally got things working however I've changed things up an bit and created a datagridview for each ID so the first Datagrid has 1 row, second datagridview has 3 entries etc.  Under each datagridview is a button created during the for loop as well.  Is there anyway to code this so each button only corresponds to the values of the row above it?  I'll be heading out soon so may not look at this again till the morning.

Comment: Anyway, you may try an old-fashioned approach of the question while we can't figure out this Cast problem... Please see my **EDIT #2** at the end of my original answer. I really hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with LinQ and lambda functions.
Let's say you have a DataTable with all those entries mixed.

Do this and you will get rows grouped by ID:

```
Dim groups = DT.Select.GroupBy(Function(row) row("ID"))
```

From now on you can extract partial datatables from it

```
Dim partialTables = groups.Select(
    Function(group)
        Dim partialTable = group.CopyToDataTable
        partialTable.TableName = group.Key
        Return partialTable
    End Function).ToList
```

Then you can query your list of tables for a specific ID, retrieve it and use it as your datasource:

```
YourDataGridView.DataSource = partialtables.FirstOrDefault(
    Function(table) table.TableName = "123")
```

**EDIT**
Below you can see a complete implementation of my suggestion:

```
Private DT As DataTable, partialTables As List(Of DataTable)
Private WithEvents CB As ComboBox, DGV As DataGridView
Private Sub q37459856()
    DT = New DataTable
    DT.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    DT.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
    DT.Columns.Add("Commens", GetType(String))
    DT.Rows.Add("aaaaaa", 1, "aaaaaa")
    DT.Rows.Add("bbbbbb", 2, "bbbbbb")
    DT.Rows.Add("cccccc", 1, "cccccc")
    DT.Rows.Add("dddddd", 2, "dddddd")
    DT.Rows.Add("eeeeee", 3, "eeeeee")
    DT.Rows.Add("ffffff", 1, "ffffff")
    DT.Rows.Add("gggggg", 2, "gggggg")
    DT.Rows.Add("hhhhhh", 3, "hhhhhh")
    DT.Rows.Add("iiiiii", 4, "iiiiii")

    Dim groups As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, DataRow)) = DT.Select.GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("ID"))

    partialTables = groups.Select(
        Function(group)
            Dim partialTable = group.CopyToDataTable
            'IGrouping(Of Integer, DataRow) implements IEnumerable(of DataRow)
            'therefore, it implements Function .CopyToDataTable() 
            partialTable.TableName = group.Key.ToString("000")
            Return partialTable
        End Function).ToList

    Dim IDs = New List(Of String)({"all"}.Concat(partialTables.Select(Function(t) t.TableName)))

    Dim F As New Form
    CB = New ComboBox With {.Dock = DockStyle.Top, .DataSource = IDs}
    F.Controls.Add(CB)
    DGV = New DataGridView With {
        .Left = CB.Left,
        .Top = CB.Top + CB.Height + 3,
        .Width = CB.Width,
        .Height = F.ClientSize.Height - CB.Top - CB.Height - 6,
        .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left + AnchorStyles.Top + AnchorStyles.Right + AnchorStyles.Bottom,
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False}
    F.Controls.Add(DGV)
    F.Show()
End Sub
Sub CB_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CB.SelectedValueChanged
    If CB.SelectedValue = "all" Then
        DGV.DataSource = DT
    Else
        DGV.DataSource = partialTables.FirstOrDefault(Function(t) t.TableName = CB.SelectedValue)
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT #2** In order to provide a working solution for the question, below goes a version with similar logic but relying on *For...Next* iterations instead of *Linq*:

```
Private DT As DataTable, partialTables As List(Of DataTable)
Private WithEvents CB As ComboBox, DGV As DataGridView
Private Sub q37459856_withoutLinq()
    DT = New DataTable
    DT.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    DT.Columns.Add("ORDER_ID", GetType(Integer))
    DT.Columns.Add("Comments", GetType(String))
    DT.Rows.Add("aaaaaa", 1, "aaaaaa")
    DT.Rows.Add("bbbbbb", 2, "bbbbbb")
    DT.Rows.Add("cccccc", 1, "cccccc")
    DT.Rows.Add("dddddd", 2, "dddddd")
    DT.Rows.Add("eeeeee", 3, "eeeeee")
    DT.Rows.Add("ffffff", 1, "ffffff")
    DT.Rows.Add("gggggg", 2, "gggggg")
    DT.Rows.Add("hhhhhh", 3, "hhhhhh")
    DT.Rows.Add("iiiiii", 4, "iiiiii")

    Dim allORDER_ID As New List(Of Integer)

    For Each dr In DT.Select
        If Not allORDER_ID.Contains(dr("ORDER_ID")) Then
            allORDER_ID.Add(dr("ORDER_ID"))
        End If
    Next

    Dim partialTable As DataTable
    partialTables = New List(Of DataTable)
    For Each ORDER_ID In allORDER_ID
        partialTable = DT.Clone
        partialTable.TableName = ORDER_ID.ToString("000")
        For Each dr In DT.Select("ORDER_ID=" & ORDER_ID)
            partialTable.ImportRow(dr)
        Next
        partialTables.Add(partialTable)
    Next

    Dim IDs = New List(Of String)({"all"})

    For Each partialTable In partialTables
        IDs.Add(partialTable.TableName)
    Next

    Dim F As New Form
    CB = New ComboBox With {.Dock = DockStyle.Top, .DataSource = IDs}
    F.Controls.Add(CB)
    DGV = New DataGridView With {
        .Left = CB.Left,
        .Top = CB.Top + CB.Height + 3,
        .Width = CB.Width,
        .Height = F.ClientSize.Height - CB.Top - CB.Height - 6,
        .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left + AnchorStyles.Top + AnchorStyles.Right + AnchorStyles.Bottom,
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False}
    F.Controls.Add(DGV)
    F.Show()
End Sub
Sub CB_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CB.SelectedValueChanged
    If CB.SelectedValue = "all" Then
        DGV.DataSource = DT
    Else
        DGV.DataSource = partialTables.FirstOrDefault(Function(t) t.TableName = CB.SelectedValue)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I can use a lot here and it make sense.   I should also have added where my first source is coming from. (above my original code is) `Dim DT As New DataTable  DT.Load(SQLMP)` (SQLMP is a sql recordset).  Will this still apply here as `GroupBy` is not a member of `DataRow`

Comment: GroupBy is a LinQ extension and applies to any object that implements IEnumerable(Of T). DT.Select() returns an array of Datarow, which implements IEnumerable(Of Datarow) and so can use GroupBy and other LinQ functions

Comment: `CopyToDataTable' is not a member of 'IGrouping(Of Object, DataRow)'.` Earlier I just hadn't taken care of my references, I should have that straight now unless I'm missing something else.

Comment: Could you show the block of code where you are getting that exception?

Comment: Sorry I've been out of the office.  What version of .NET are you using and did you have to add any special references?  I still get the error above about CopyToDataTable not a member of IGrouping and now Field is not a member of DataRow.

Comment: No problem. I'm using .NET 4.5. Check if you have `Option Strict Off` and `Option Infer On`. These are needed in order to take advantage of _lambda_ expressions.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5.  `Option Strict Off` and `Option Infer On`

Comment: Does your project reference `System.Collections`, `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Linq`?

Comment: Actually what I was missing was `System.Data.DataSetExtentions`

Comment: Could you get it to work after adding the missing references?

Comment: So I'm not sure if any of this changes things using bound data but look above I'll put what initial error I received.

Comment: If the error persists, please post the code with your implementation of my suggestion as an edit to your question and I'll take a look.